# Position bottom footer always

Tags: html, css

I have footer, but have problem with google map.

```
 <table class="sortable table table-bordered table-responsive " id="table"  ng-show="bsalInfo">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="att in bsalInfo track by $index">
               <td>{{att.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

start This script my google map

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;  height: 60%; position: absolute;margin-top: 45px;">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

finish This script my google map

This css footer

```
footer{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0 ;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Where is my problem?
1. My footer is over map, i want footer always on page.
2 When there is a scroll on the footer page always sitting down, no matter how many results there is on the page.

Comment: footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0 ;
    left:0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

Try with this code, please hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I you want your footer to be positioned at the bottom of the page, but not **fixed**.

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>        
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <div id="footer"></div>     
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
      height: 100%;
    }

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;  
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  background: green;
  height: 90px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: My footer now is position over map and scroll page footer go up

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you have any element `<footer>` shown in your code. But if you want the footer to persistantly remain at the bottom of your page, use `position: fixed;` along with `bottom: 0;` and your other styling

Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)